# How to init a custom cell when using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier method?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I registered a custom cell call MyTableViewCell in tableview, and return a cell in datasource using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier method.

Now, my problem are
1: my custom cell initializer(initWithIdentifier: andModel:) can't get called.
2: when I get a reused cell, how can I update cell content with its according model?

Comment: Don't use an initialiser. It doesn't really work when you are reusing an object. Simply provide another function that accepts a model and configures the cell as required.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create one method in your custom cell to show data for it. Here is example..

```
class AddNotesTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    //MARK: - Outlets

    //MARK: - Variables
   override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
      super.init(style:style , reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
  }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
     //MARK: - Life cycle

    func setupCell(dic:NSMutableDictionary){
    // Show your data in UILabel, UITextfield...
    }
}
```

You can call **setupCell** method from your **cellForItemAtIndexPath** method. You just need to pass your current dictionary and cell will use to show data.